# How do I insert the results of a cross join into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this SQL to create a cross join and insert the results into a third  table. Any ideas why this doesn't work? The cross join works when run by itself. The insert also runs standalone but not when thet wo statements are merged.

```
INSERT INTO Person (FirstName, LastName) 
VALUES (Select fn.Name, ln.Name from FirstName as fn cross join LastName as ln);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName)
    Select fn.Name, ln.Name
    from FirstName as fn cross join LastName as ln;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the `VALUES` part to insert in these instances:

```
INSERT INTO Person (FirstName, LastName) Values (Select fn.Name, ln.Name from FirstName as fn cross join LastName as ln)
```

The following SQL should work: *(This code does not actually work - see below update)*

```
INSERT INTO Person
SELECT 
    FirstName = fn.Name, 
    LastName = ln.Name 
FROM FirstName AS fn 
CROSS JOIN LastName AS ln
```

When using a `SELECT` statement to insert values you don't need to use the `INSERT INTO tableName (...CSV of column names...) VALUES (... CSV of values ... )` syntax, that is designed for inserting explicitly defined *(Also not completely accurate - see below update)*:

```
INSERT INTO Person 
    (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES
    ('John','Smith')
    ,('Jane','Doe')`
```

**Update & Code Correction due to comments added Stuart Ainsworth:**

The following code has been updated because of the comments received, I have kept the above code the same for reference (on how not to do it!) and to keep the comments relevant, however it should be noted that as pointed out and demonstrated in the SQL fiddle, the previous code will not work.

The example which would work uses the INSERT template `INSERT INTO (... CSV of values ...) SELECT ... FROM ... etc...`. Unlike previously stated the defining of columns as with `INSERT INTO (... CSV of values ...)` is NOT purely for explicit insertions and can be used with a select statement. (The following is also now pretty much the same as the accepted answer above.)

```
INSERT INTO Person 
    (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT 
    fn.Name 
    ,ln.Name 
FROM FirstName AS fn 
CROSS JOIN LastName AS ln
```

Comment: Your suggestion will work, assuming that the PERSON table only has two columns that are in the same order as the SELECT statement (firstname, lastname).  The ideal solution would be to specify the column names as part of the INSERT clause.

Comment: You might be right, but in my experience because the column names have been explicitly defined e.g. `FirstName = fn.Name` so long as there are no other fields which are required it should run successfully. (Though in fairness if there are other fields which are required any of the above solutions won't work)